# Qt5 application wont draw any windows on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt5

I have an old Qt4 code that I ported to Qt5 and built (gcc4.8, Ubuntu). The program does not show any GUI windows, but prints its console output just fine.

Finally, I reduced my entire `main()` to the minimal code below, and have got the same behaviour: the "exec..." is printed and program is silently running (no exit, no crash), but no windows appears.

What issue should I consider?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;

    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Simple example");
    window.show();
    std::cout << "exec...\n";
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Where do you relate (or associate) the window to the application?  In many GUI applications you have to insert or add the window to the app.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this code example should create empty window of size (250, 150).

Comment: Which backend?  X11, egl or linuxfb?  The above code works as expected in X11 for me.  Be sure that it's not been buried somewhere in your window manager (if you are running a window manager).

Comment: @TobySpeight I know nothing about "egl", but I think it is not linuxfb. I use xorg for my desktop. What distro (and version) do you use? How did you installed the Qt5?

Comment: I built the above with `g++ -std=c++14 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses  $(pkg-config --cflags -libs Qt5Widgets)  -o 38173496` using Qt version 5.6.1+dfsg-2 on Debian (just installed with `aptitude install qtbase5-dev`, so nothing out of the ordinary).  I'm using FVWM as window manager, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the platform plugin to be missing or at the wrong place if loading / showing a simple Widget fails.
Look for error output in your debugging environment (something like "Failed to load platform plugin").
Which platform are you using? Check your applications directory structure!

Comment: What kind of thing do you mean by "platform"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the window manager (icewm) that doesn't support the way Qt 5 creates windows.  It's [fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/icewm/git/ci/395cfbb56a4adaee7028cfcbe6177ec0b94c181d/) in [icewm 1.3.8](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=751794#10), so if you can update to that, or use a different window manager, that would fix your problem.